# Comparison loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a nested list

```
combine <- list(c('A', 'B', 'C'), c('D', 'H', 'G', 'J'), c('A', 'E'))
```

and a df

```
df <- data.frame(appln_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 9, 9), 
                 prior_year = c(1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1997,1998,1998,1998,1998,2000,2000,2000),
                 IPC = c('B','E','E','B','H','J','D','H','J','D','E','A','E','B'))
```

I want to aggregate `IPC` according to `appln_id` (eg: `for appln_id=1: c('B','E')`, `for appln_id=2: c('E','B')`, `for appln_id=4: c('H','J','D')`, etc.). Then for each value of `prior_year`, I want to compare the `IPC` sets to elements of the list `combine`.

For the `IPC` set that is not a subset of any element of `combine`, I want to save its data in `df` in another dataframe called `new` as follows:

```
new <- data.frame(appln_id = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
                  prior_year = c(1997,1997,1998,1998,1998,1998),
                  IPC = c('B','E','H','J','D','E'))
```

and add this `IPC` set into `combine` as follows:

```
combine <- list(c('A', 'B', 'C'), c('D', 'H', 'G', 'J'), c('A', 'E'), c('B', 'E'), c('D','E','J','H'))
```

This is my code:

```
new <- data.frame(appln_id=integer(),prio_year=integer(), IPC=character()) 
new_combine=list()
prio_year <- unique(df$prio_year)
appln_id <- unique(df$appln_id)
for (i in prio_year){
  for (j in appln_id){
    x <- sort((df[(df$prio_year==i) & (df$appln_id==j),3])[[1]])
    for (k in combine){
      if (all(x %in% k) == FALSE){
        new <- rbind(new, df[df$appln_id==j,])
        new_combine[[length(new_combine)+1]] <- x
      }
    }
  }
  combine <- c(combine,unique(new_combine))
}
```

However, it takes too long for my code to run. Could anyone have another way to make it faster? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that is only a single loop. Up front, though, I changed `$IPC` from `factor` to `character`, since merging differing factor levels can be a little annoying. (If you're on R-4.0 or `$IPC` is already `character`, then no need to do this step.)

```r
df$usable <- TRUE
df$grps <- interaction(df$appln_id, df$prior_year)
newlist <- list()
for (grp in levels(df$grps)) {
  rows <- df$grps == grp & df$usable
  if (!length(rows)) next
  thisIPC <- df$IPC[rows]
  matches <- sapply(combine, function(comb) all(thisIPC %in% comb))
  if (any(matches)) {
    # repeat
  } else {
    # new!
    combine <- c(combine, list(thisIPC))
    newlist <- c(newlist, list(df[rows,]))
    df$usable[rows] <- FALSE
  }
}
df <- df[df$usable,]
new <- do.call(rbind, newlist)
df$usable <- df$grps <- 
  new$usable <- new$grps <- NULL

df
#    appln_id prior_year IPC
# 3         2       1997   E
# 4         2       1997   B
# 5         4       1997   H
# 6         4       1997   J
# 7         4       1997   D
# 12        5       2000   A
# 13        9       2000   E
# 14        9       2000   B
new
#    appln_id prior_year IPC
# 1         1       1997   B
# 2         1       1997   E
# 8         3       1998   H
# 9         3       1998   J
# 10        3       1998   D
# 11        3       1998   E
str(combine)
# List of 5
#  $ : chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"
#  $ : chr [1:4] "D" "H" "G" "J"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "A" "E"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "B" "E"
#  $ : chr [1:4] "H" "J" "D" "E"
```

Notes:

- I create the `$grps` variable to make easy single-loop grouping; once this loop is done, feel free to remove it. Using `factor` and then `levels` ensures that I iterate over else present combination, nothing more.
- I may be going to more extremes than necessary, but iteratively growing frames is bad in the long-term for performance: each time you "add rows", the entire frame is perfectly copied in memory, so with each addition, you duplicate the memory take for the frame. Granted, the memory is cleared, but it is a "known thing" that this slows down noticeably asymptotically. (See chapter 2, *Growing Objects*, in the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).) This applies (to a slightly-lesser degree) to iteratively removing rows, too.

  Because of this, I don't actually change the contents of the frame until the very end. To accommodate this, I also add a column `$usable` to indicate if it should be removed in the end. (In the unlikely event that you run this code *twice* on the same frame, I also use `$enable` in grabbing `$IPC`, that might just be overly-defensive.)

  Post-loop, I remove the relevant rows from `df` *once*, and do a single row-concatenation (`rbind`) on the `newlist`, which is a list with frames (or nothing, if nothing happened).

Comment: could you sort the elements in IPC sets alphabetically please?

Comment: `df[order(df$IPC),]`?

Comment: No, I mean, in each IPC set. For example, the 5th element of resulted 'combine' should be c("D", "E", "J", "H") instead of c("H", "J", "D", "E").

Comment: `combine <- c(combine, list(sort(thisIPC)))`?

Comment: hi, due to large datasets, it takes too long for the code to execute and actually I only care whether appln_ids in a list called `main`, for example, `main <- c(1,2,3)` are in the resulted list `new`. So I add `df$main <- ifelse(df$appln_id %in% main$appln_id, TRUE, FALSE)` into `df` before the loop, and `if (df$main[rows]== FALSE) {
    combine <- unique(c(combine, list(sort(thisIPC))))
    df$usable[rows] <- FALSE
  } else {` before matching step. But it doesn't work. Could you please help me once more time, please?

Comment: (1) `ifelse(cond, TRUE, FALSE)` is unnecessarily complex, just use `cond` by itself. (2) Following that `df$main` is a column and `rows` is a vector of arbitrary length, then `if (df$main[rows]==FALSE)` is broken: `if` **requires** length exactly 1, so unless you force `rows` to always be length 1, it will break. (Also, `cond==FALSE` --> `! cond`.)

Comment: I use `if (!unique(df$main[rows]))` instead and the same error rises again. I think rows should always not length 0 because in the code you provided me, there is `if (!length(rows)) next` before the added `if (!unique(df$main[rows]))`.

Comment: `!unique(df$main[rows])` is also not guaranteed to be length 1. Since your logic is likely to be length not-1, then stop trying to use `if`, it is not the tool for this trick.

Comment: could you tell me how I could deal with this please? I have been struggling with it for 2 months and still messing around :(

Comment: It sounds like this has evolved from a data-management question to a logical-flow problem. It might be best to open a new question, I'll try to take a look at it later.

Comment: Thank you so much indeed. I have opened a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383120/r-argument-is-of-length-zero