# R argument of length zero in if statement

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a df

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                 year = c(1997,1997,1997,1997,1998,1998,1998),
                 usable = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                 main = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
```

When I execute the code

```
df$id_year <- interaction(df$id, df$year)
for (i in levels(df$id_year)) {
  rows <- df$id_year == i & df$usable
  if (!unique(df$main[rows]) {
    print("yes")
  }
}
```

the error of "argument of length zero" appears for the line `if (!unique(df$main[rows])`. Could anyone please explain why and how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: What do you intend by `!unique(df$main[rows]`? It is a vector, but you seem to be thinking of it as a Boolean value.

Comment: oh I see, so can I change it into a value by unlist()?

Comment: Liselotte, I've [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077664/comparison-loop/62078027#comment112080907_62078027) that that specific code does not work. What do you think `unique` returns? Try `unique(c(1,1,2,3))` and see that it is (1) not `logical` or something that can be inferred as such; and (2) based on what the output looks like, it has no guarantee of being length 1.

Comment: You need `df$id_year <- interaction(df$id, df$year, drop = TRUE)` and `if (length(unique(df$main[rows])) > 0)`

Comment: @r2evans: i'm so sorry that I keep asking and using it. But because i think that `for (i in levels(df$id_year))` refers to each single id, and each id should have the same value of either TRUE or FALSE in its all rows in df$main.

Comment: @akrun: thank you very much indeed. it works now.

Comment: Lisolette, don't apologize that you keep asking ... you won't get an answer if you don't ask. I'm glad akrun's answer works for you, I hope you can move forward quickly after that. :-)

Comment: @r2evans: thank you so much indeed for your help during these 2 months. Your help means a lot to me. To be honest I'm embarrassed keeping asking the same question again and again when you've tried to explain it to me. Thank you for your kind support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely due to creation of unused `levels` because by default `drop = FALSE` in `interaction`

```
df$id_year <- interaction(df$id, df$year, drop = TRUE)
```

In the loop, as others have mentioned the `!unique(` is not clear.  If we are checking the `length` of `unique` elements are greater than 0 (`if (length(unique(df$main[rows])) > 0)`, it would print "yes"

```
for (i in levels(df$id_year)) {
   rows <- df$id_year == i & df$usable
   if (length(unique(df$main[rows])) > 0) {
     print("yes")
   }
 }
#[1] "yes"
#[1] "yes"
#[1] "yes"
```